# Implementing OnClickListener for dynamically created buttons in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I dynamically created buttons through code rather than from XML.

The code is as below :

```
    dynamicview = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llayout);
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams lprams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

     for(int i=0;i<nob;i++){
         Button btn = new Button(this);
         btn.setId(i+1);
         btn.setText("Button"+(i+1));
         btn.setLayoutParams(lprams);
         dynamicview.addView(btn);
     }
```

I am not finding a way in which I can implement OnClickListener to each of these buttons so that I can perform action based on the reference I get.

Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue. ?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: The provided answers are correct. The view passed into the onClickListender is the Button and can be cast.  Button btn = (Button)v;  Then used to access the id that you set.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

See the code below:

```
for(int i=0;i<nob;i++) {
    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setId(i+1);
    btn.setText("Button"+(i+1));
    btn.setLayoutParams(lprams);
    final int index = i;
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("TAG", "The index is" + index);
        }
    });
    dynamicview.addView(btn);
}
```

My example is pretty simple, but demonstrates how you can get the button index into the `OnClickListeber`. You can access any `final` field in the declared anonymous classes (e..g the `OnClickListener`).

Comment: what if I want to perform some other action on different button ? I think If I write some code in your click listener It will be same FOR ALL OF THE BUTTONS, how can I achieve different functionality on each button?

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO Logical question with simple answer. In order to have different functionality you need to define different `OnClickListener`s. Do it in whatever manner you like and just fill them in an array `OnClickListener [] listeners`. Then in the for do `btn.setOnClickListener(listeners[i]);`

Answer (score 8):

```
   for(int i=0;i<nob;i++){
         Button btn = new Button(this);
         btn.setId(i+1);
         btn.setText("Button"+(i+1));
         btn.setOnClickListener(btnclick); <<<<<<<set click
         btn.setLayoutParams(lprams);
         dynamicview.addView(btn);
     }
```

And add this listner outside the any method and inside class

```
 OnClickListener btnclick = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            switch(view.getId()){
              case 1:
               //first button click
              break;
               //Second button click
              case 2:
              break;
              case 3:
               //third button click
              break;
              case 4:
               //fourth button click
              break;
            .
            .
            .
             default:
              break;
              }

        }
    };
```

Comment: the order in this corde is incorrect. you want to make the listener prior to the loop.

Comment: not a proper solution as I would not know the number of buttons before hand and moreover I would not want to add a case for each button.

Comment: @mirroredAbstraction this is most proper soluton for each button click...and if you dont for all then need only onclick method

Answer (score 2):

Use a `List` and add `Button`s you create to that `List`

```
List<Button> list = new ArrayList<Button>();
```

Now add your button to that List

```
for(int i=0;i<nob;i++){
         Button btn = new Button(this);
         btn.setId(i+1);
         btn.setText("Button"+(i+1));
         btn.setLayoutParams(lprams);
         dynamicview.addView(btn);
         list.add(btn);
     }
```

Then use advanced for loop to iterate through the list and add click listener for each Button..

```
for(Button btn : list){
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will be helpful for somebody I wanted to use the one counter variable for group of dynamically created buttons:

I've created the array for counters:

```
int[] squatReps;
```

From preferences I've taken the quantity of elements:

```
squatReps = new int[squatSets];  // where squatSets is taken from preferences
```

And finally we create the buttons

```
for (int i = 0; i < squatSets; i++){
                squatReps[i] = Integer.parseInt(sharedPreferences.getString("squats_reps", "0"));
                final Button squat_b = new Button(this.getActivity());
                squat_b.setId(i);
                squat_b.setText("");
                squat_b.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                final int index = i;
                squat_b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        squat_b.setText(Integer.toString(squatReps[index]--));    
                        startTimer();                                
                    }
                });
                panel_1.addView(squat_b);
```

Answer (score 1):

its the same thing...

```
for(int i=0;i<nob;i++){
         Button btn = new Button(this);
         btn.setId(i+1);
         btn.setText("Button"+(i+1));
         btn.setLayoutParams(lprams);
         btn.setOnCLickListsener(new listener());
         dynamicview.addView(btn);
     }

listener implemnets OnClickListenere{

public void onClick(View v){

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0;i<nob;i++){
         Button btn = new Button(this);
         btn.setId(i+1);
         btn.setText("Button"+(i+1));
         btn.setLayoutParams(lprams);
         btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               /////Do some job on button click
            }
        }); 
         dynamicview.addView(btn);
     }
```