# How to detect onClick for a view in adapter which is dynamically created

Tags: android

**What i am doing**:: I have a adapter for which i am adding view in each row dynamically

**What i am trying to do**:: I am trying to detect `onclick` for `imageView` which was dynamically created

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TableLayout table_layout = null;
    private List<Map<String,CharSequence>> mListLayoutData=new ArrayList<Map<String,CharSequence>>();
    private Map<String, CharSequence> objMap = new HashMap<String, CharSequence>();

    private HFGridView gridView;

    private int screenWidth=0;
    private int screenHeight=0;

    Configuration newConfig;
    int numOfColumns=0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        gridView = (HFGridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        table_layout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);     
        gridView.setNumColumns(1);

        //Get the Width and the height of the screeen
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
        if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        {

            //Portrait Mode
            numOfColumns=(int) Math.ceil(metrics.widthPixels/160);
            gridView.setColumnWidth(metrics.widthPixels);

        }
        else if(config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {
            //Landscape Mode
            numOfColumns=(int) Math.ceil(metrics.widthPixels/160);
            gridView.setColumnWidth(metrics.widthPixels);

        }

        View header1 = getHeader("Header");
        View footer1 = getFooter("Footer");

        gridView.addHeaderView(header1);
        gridView.addFooterView(footer1);

        objMap.put("Starter","HEADER");
        mListLayoutData.add(objMap);
        if(numOfColumns==3){
            objMap = new HashMap<String, CharSequence>();
            objMap.put("1","starter");
            objMap.put("2","starter");
            objMap.put("3","starter");
            mListLayoutData.add(objMap);
            objMap = new HashMap<String, CharSequence>();
            objMap.put("4","starter");
            objMap.put("5","starter");
            mListLayoutData.add(objMap);
        }else{
            objMap = new HashMap<String, CharSequence>();
            objMap.put("1","starter");
            objMap.put("2","starter");
            mListLayoutData.add(objMap);
            objMap = new HashMap<String, CharSequence>();
            objMap.put("3","starter");
            objMap.put("4","starter");
            mListLayoutData.add(objMap);
            objMap = new HashMap<String, CharSequence>();
            objMap.put("5","starter");
            mListLayoutData.add(objMap);

        }

        gridView.setListener(new HFGridView.HFGridViewListener() {
            @Override
            public void readyToDisposeItems() {
                gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }



    private BaseAdapter adapter = new BaseAdapter() {


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            //return 1;
            return mListLayoutData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            TableLayout table_layout;
            ImageView imageView = null;
            TableRow table_row = null;
            LinearLayout linearLayout=null;



            if (view == null) {
                //Create the tableLayout and add params to it
                table_layout=new TableLayout(MainActivity.this);
                table_layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                //table_layout.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
            } else {
                table_layout=(TableLayout) view;
            }

            final Map<String, CharSequence> objMap= mListLayoutData.get(position);

            //Create the tableRow and add params to it
            table_row = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
            table_row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            //linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            // inner for loop
            for (Entry<String, CharSequence> entry : objMap.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                CharSequence value = entry.getValue();


                if(value=="HEADER"){
                    TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                    textView.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    textView.setText(key);
                    textView.setTextSize(20);
                    textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.redColor));
                    textView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                    table_row.addView(textView);
                }else{
                    //Create the Linear Layout and add params to it
                    linearLayout=new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
                    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                    //Create the ImageView and add params to it
                    imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(160, 100));
                    //imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(imageView.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.eight));
                    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.eleven);

                    //Create the TextView and add params to it
                    TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                    textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    textView.setText(key);
                    textView.setTextSize(12);
                    textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.redColor));

                    linearLayout.addView(imageView);
                    linearLayout.addView(textView);
                    table_row.addView(linearLayout);

                }   
            }

            table_layout.addView(table_row);
            return table_layout;
        }
    };

    private View getHeader(String text) {
        View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.headerTextView);
        textView.setText(text);

        return header;
    }

    private View getFooter(String text) {
        View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) footer.findViewById(R.id.footerTextView);
        textView.setText(text);
        return footer;
    }
}
```

Comment: setClickListener on imageView in getView and handle that.

Comment: You can use, setTag to that dynamic created imageview and in onclick listener you can get tag and you will get which imageview is clicked

Comment: @shayan pourvatan .... That is not working for Dynamically generated views ..... OnClicklistener throws error on loading the class when i do in getview method!

Comment: @Rohit ... Can you show a snippet as your answer !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view

Comment: @Devrath Are You Sure? because i don't think so at all, I do that many many time, set click listener use set tag with position and getTag in onClick method then you get position of list item then do what ever you want

Comment: Also look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890100/recognizing-a-button-from-a-dynamic-view

Comment: @shayan pourvatan ... Oops ! .... Sorry my mistake .... What i needed to do is set the onClickListener berore adding the views ! ...Solved !

Answer (score 0):

Found Solution to my answer !

[This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10673676/1083093) and [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2580975/shayan-pourvatan) helped me in finding the solution, sharing it so it might be helpful to someone !

---

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TableLayout table_layout = null;
    private List<Map<String,CharSequence>> mListLayoutData=new ArrayList<Map<String,CharSequence>>();
    private Map<String, CharSequence> objMap = new HashMap<String, CharSequence>();

    private HFGridView gridView;

    private int screenWidth=0;
    private int screenHeight=0;

    Configuration newConfig;
    int numOfColumns=0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        gridView = (HFGridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        table_layout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);     
        gridView.setNumColumns(1);

        //Get the Width and the height of the screeen
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
        if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        {

            //Portrait Mode
            numOfColumns=(int) Math.ceil(metrics.widthPixels/160);
            gridView.setColumnWidth(metrics.widthPixels);

        }
        else if(config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {
            //Landscape Mode
            numOfColumns=(int) Math.ceil(metrics.widthPixels/160);
            gridView.setColumnWidth(metrics.widthPixels);

        }

        View header1 = getHeader("Header");
        View footer1 = getFooter("Footer");

        gridView.addHeaderView(header1);
        gridView.addFooterView(footer1);

        objMap.put("Starter","HEADER");
        mListLayoutData.add(objMap);
        if(numOfColumns==3){
            objMap = new HashMap<String, CharSequence>();
            objMap.put("1","starter");
            objMap.put("2","starter");
            objMap.put("3","starter");
            mListLayoutData.add(objMap);
            objMap = new HashMap<String, CharSequence>();
            objMap.put("4","starter");
            objMap.put("5","starter");
            mListLayoutData.add(objMap);
        }else{
            objMap = new HashMap<String, CharSequence>();
            objMap.put("1","starter");
            objMap.put("2","starter");
            mListLayoutData.add(objMap);
            objMap = new HashMap<String, CharSequence>();
            objMap.put("3","starter");
            objMap.put("4","starter");
            mListLayoutData.add(objMap);
            objMap = new HashMap<String, CharSequence>();
            objMap.put("5","starter");
            mListLayoutData.add(objMap);

        }

        gridView.setListener(new HFGridView.HFGridViewListener() {
            @Override
            public void readyToDisposeItems() {
                gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }



    private BaseAdapter adapter = new BaseAdapter() {


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            //return 1;
            return mListLayoutData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            TableLayout table_layout;
            ImageView imageView = null;
            TableRow table_row = null;
            LinearLayout linearLayout=null;



            if (view == null) {
                //Create the tableLayout and add params to it
                table_layout=new TableLayout(MainActivity.this);
                table_layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                //table_layout.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
            } else {
                table_layout=(TableLayout) view;
            }

            final Map<String, CharSequence> objMap= mListLayoutData.get(position);

            //Create the tableRow and add params to it
            table_row = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
            table_row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            //linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            // inner for loop
            for (Entry<String, CharSequence> entry : objMap.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                CharSequence value = entry.getValue();


                if(value=="HEADER"){
                    TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                    textView.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    textView.setText(key);
                    textView.setTextSize(20);
                    textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.redColor));
                    textView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                    table_row.addView(textView);
                }else{
                    //Create the Linear Layout and add params to it
                    linearLayout=new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
                    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                    //Create the ImageView and add params to it
                    imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(160, 100));
                    //imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(imageView.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.eight));
                    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.eleven);

                    //Create the TextView and add params to it
                    TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                    textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    textView.setText(key);
                    textView.setTextSize(12);
                    textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.redColor));


                    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                    linearLayout.addView(imageView);
                    linearLayout.addView(textView);
                    table_row.addView(linearLayout);

                }   
            }





            table_layout.addView(table_row);
            return table_layout;
        }
    };

    private View getHeader(String text) {
        View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.headerTextView);
        textView.setText(text);

        return header;
    }

    private View getFooter(String text) {
        View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) footer.findViewById(R.id.footerTextView);
        textView.setText(text);
        return footer;
    }
}
```