# Get clicked TextView in ScrollView/LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, textview, android-scrollview

I have in my program a scroll view with a linearlayout inside of it. I add dynamically TextView's to the linearlayout and I have no way to know how much TextView's I'll end up with. When a certain TextView is clicked I need to get it's text. Any idea what is the best way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

I've tried to add a listener to the text view but I am not sure how to get the text. I saw in some posts that you can do a listener to the LinearLayour/ScrollView though I am not sure what is the best option.

This happenes every time a message is added:

```
TextView messageText = new TextView(RecordedMessagesScreen.this);
messageText.setText(content);
messageText.setClickable(true);

messageText.setOnClickListener(RecordedMessagesScreen.this.textViewListener);
RecordedMessagesScreen.this.messagesLayout.addView(messageText);
```

this is the listener:

```
this.textViewListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra("message", ***NEED TO GET THE TEXT***)
    }
};
```

Comment: Hello @Netanel , can you share us the code?

Comment: Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673628/implementing-onclicklistener-for-dynamically-created-buttons-in-android)

Comment: Hi @Zuhrain , I've added some code. Is it enough?

Comment: @TamirAbutbul if I do "final String" I can access it when clicked?

Comment: yes , you can access it but you cant change it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the class level declare a `String` variable:

```
private String text = "";
```

and a `View.OnClickListener` variable:

```
private View.OnClickListener listener;
```

Initialize the listener in `onCreate()` of your activity like this:

```
listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) v;
        text = tv.getText().toString();
    }
};
```

and every time you create a new `TextView` set the listener:

```
textView.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

This way the variable `text` each time you click a `TextView` will get the clicked `TextView`'s text.
You can customize the code inside `onClick()` yo suit your needs.